# How to match filename words without the extension using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I want to match the words in a filename without characters like underscores (_) and the file extension. For example, if i have the files image_one.jpg and image_two.png then how can I match only `image one` and `image two`? I am not sure how to exclude the underscore and the .extension.

So far, I have `\w*_\w*` but it matches the file name including the underscore i.e. `image_one` and `image_two`

Comment: Consider doing it in multiple steps without regular expressions. Remove the extension first by splitting the string, then filter out the underscores and join it back.

Comment: elclanrs makes a good suggestion. If you need to filter out underscores, or more than underscores, there's always string.replace() to help you.

Comment: Thank you @elclanrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `\w*_\w*` could possibly also match a single `_` as the word chars are optional.

As `\w` also matches an underscore, you can exclude it from `\w` by using a negated character class.`[^\W_]`.

To get both values, you could use 2 capturing groups and if the pattern must only match at the end of the string you can add `$` at the end.

```
([^\W_]+)_([^\W_]+)\.\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `([^\W_]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times a word char except `_`
- `_` Match the underscore
- `([^\W_]+)` Capture group 2, same as for group 1
- `\.\w+` Match a `.` and 1+ word chars (or `\.(?:jpg|png)` to be more precise)

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/axZOBi/1/)

```js
const regex = /([^\W_]+)_([^\W_]+)\.\w+/;
[
  "image_one.jpg",
  "image_two.png"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex).slice(1)));
```